# Namespace of .ForSourceMember method in AutoMapper

Tags: namespaces, automapper

For the life of me I cannot find the name space of the .ForSourceMember() method mentioned in [automapper how to ignore property in source item that does not exist in destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052579/automapper-how-to-ignore-property-in-source-item-that-does-not-exist-in-destinat). At least initially, it appears the asker was too (see Reedemed1's comment on Richard's answer).

Does anyone know what namespace this method resides in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AutoMapper namespace. See [source file](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/035262f297613c75d394b8f0dcbd4f41390975eb/src/AutoMapper/Internal/MappingExpression.cs)