# Automapper System.ArgumentException when mapping from class with generic methods

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to use AutoMapper to map Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage to a lightweight DTO. I have the following code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<BrokeredMessage, QueueMessage>()
            .ForMember(dest=>dest.ID, src=>src.MapFrom(x=>x.SequenceNumber));
```

But this is producing an exception:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional
>   information: Method T GetBodyT is a generic method definition

Would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: what does the definitions of BrokeredMessage and QueueMessage look like?

Comment: BrokeredMessage is just Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage

QueueMessage is simple class
`public class QueueMessage
    {
        public long SequenceNo { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: I think you're looking in the wrong place. With the info on hand, I would say the exception is being generated when you call an instance BrokeredMessage.  See the provided links.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh144211.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh125098.aspx

Comment: Also the Queue message doesn't have an ID property in the definition you provided.

Comment: Also also your classes don't seem to have a 1 to 1 match on properties.  I don't remember the exception thrown for it, but  automapper must define each property it uses.  You will need to handle that, or if you don't want those properties to be dealt with by auto mapper you need to ignore them.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052579/automapper-how-to-ignore-property-in-source-item-that-does-not-exist-in-destinat