# Ignore a property in AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'm using Automapper to copy one object properties to other and later will update in database using EF.

Question is how to tell Automapper copy every property but ignore a particular property (in this case it will be Id). I'm new to AutoMapper and just have done this code. I don't have other configurations or use of AutoMap in project.

```
Mapper.Map(lead, existingLead);
```

I have downloaded AutoMapper form here https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Comment: possible duplicate of [automapper how to ignore property in source item that does not exist in destination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052579/automapper-how-to-ignore-property-in-source-item-that-does-not-exist-in-destinat)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

On your `Mapper.CreateMap<Type1, Type2>()` you can use either

```
.ForSourceMember(x => x.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
```

or

```
.ForMember(x => x.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
```

UPDATE:
It seems like `.Ignore()` is renamed to `.DoNotValidate()` according to the AutoMapper [docs](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#forsourcemember-ignore).

Comment: sorry where I can find Mapper.CreateMap ? I just have installed in using Nuget packages and the line of code I added in question is only line I did.

Comment: @user576510 It should just be under the AutoMapper namespace. Just create that on its own line (followed by .ForMember() or .ForSourceMember() depending on how you are binding) and you should be good to go :)

Comment: @John Why I need to use `Ignore`? Properties which are missing in a destination type will get their default value.

Comment: @JosephKatzman I dunno maybe its changed in the last 2 years ;)

Comment: @JosephKatzman: opt.Ignore() tells AutoMapper to not map a value to that destination member. AutoMapper maps to destination members by default so, if there is no destination member, the member doesn't get mapped anyway (and should generate a compiler error). If the destination does contain the member, AutoMapper tries to find a source member to map from, unless you use Ignore().

Answer (score 1):

I use this extension method:

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreMember<TSource, TDestination>(
    this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> map, Expression<Func<TDestination, object>> selector)
{
    map.ForMember(selector, config => config.Ignore());
    return map;
}
```

and I use it like this

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyType1, MyType2>().IgnoreMember(m => m.PropertyName);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, I m new to automapper, do i need add some configurations in config file ? I only have done line of code which I mention in qeustion. Wehre I should use Mapper.CreateMap ?

Comment: When your app initializes, you need to call a Initialize method that will setup all the mappings of your classes. See this guide to know more Automapper https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started.